# NPM script naming convention

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a script in my `package.json` that looks something like this:

```
{
    ...
    scripts: {
        ...
        "testdb:e2e": "TESTDB_ENV='...' gulp mocha:e2e:backend && gulp mocha:e2e:frontend"
   }
    ...
}
```

And I want to add a script to specifically call backend or frontend with my test environment. But I wanted to know what the NPM script namespacing convention is, but I can't find documentation on it. I'm thinking of namespacing with a colon like gulp does, something like this:

```
"testdb:e2e": "TESTDB_ENV='...' gulp mocha:e2e:backend && gulp mocha:e2e:frontend",
"testdb:e2e:backend": "TESTDB_ENV='...' gulp mocha:e2e:backend",
"testdb:e2e:frontend": "TESTDB_ENV='...' gulp mocha:e2e:frontend"
```

Is there a specific naming convention for namespacing npm scripts?

Comment: I don't know of a convention.

Comment: @EvanHahn: there's a package that enforces the `:` convention but [without explanation](https://github.com/bahmutov/colon-names/issues/1). I've just asked the author about that.

Comment: Duplicate of a newer, but better voted question - [What is colon : in npm script names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606101/what-is-colon-in-npm-script-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t.

Internally, however, npm uses things like `pretest` and `posttest`.

It’s not the best thing so you might prefer to use your own.

Comment: on a side note: you can change the value of `testdb:e2e` to become `npm run testdb:e2e:backend  && npm run testdb:e2e:frontend `

Comment: actually, `pre` and `post` prefixes work with any custom script name, not just `test`