# What is colon : in npm script names?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell

Trying to figure out what putting : in an npm script name does.  For example:

**package.json**

```
"test:ci": "rest of script"
```

what would `:ci` do?  running `npm run test:ci` fails

I can't find anything bash syntax really.

Comment: Nothing to do with `bash`. Apparently it's a convention that could be [better explained](https://github.com/bahmutov/colon-names/issues/1).

Comment: It is *slightly* related to bash (or any shell, to be exact): the most common character for separating words is a space, however two such words would be separate shell arguments (but we want one shell argument - a task name that happened to have spaces). The solution is to enclosed them in quotes, which is a bit cumbersome (e.g. `app run "test stuff"` vs `app run test:stuff`).

As to the original reasons, I believe some other task managers use(d) colons and this was simply "ported" over to npm.

Answer (score 54):

I believe it's just a naming convention to group a set of related tasks.  For example you might have

```
"test:ci": ...
"test:units": ....
"test:integration"...
```

In this case it is grouping a related set of test tasks.

It would be down to the package author to specify.  You can split tasks out like described in the answer above and then have a 'global' `test` command which combines each of them e.g. `test:ci && test:unit && test:integration` enabling you to run them all at once or when individually when needed.

You can use `npm-run-all` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all)) and use the command `npm-run-all test:*`, which would then find all scripts starting with the `test:` group.

Comment: but how is it grouping?  what's it actually doing?  what's the benefit?

Comment: @PositiveGuy I've updated the original answer with some further context/examples.

Comment: There is no "answer above". :'(

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's just a naming convention it doesn't do anything other than what this post explains. When you have a lot of scripts, it helps to create a human readable group like this and also by using the `npm-run-all` you can run all of them or run individual scripts as needed.

Comment: pretest will not work on tasks with colon. seems stupid

Answer (score 14):

I solved this by running - `"npm run <scriptName>"`

Within my `package.json` file, I had two "start scripts"

`start`: `nodemon server.js`

`start:elasticsearch`: `docker run elasticsearch..`

Solved with `npm run start:elasticsearch`

Comment: why can i call npm test but to call my custom test script like testHeadless i have to call npm run testHeadless?

Comment: Solved what exactly?

Comment: @JesseBoyd this is simply the convention adopted by the npm developers. It is likely to avoid namespace conflicts between user-defined script names and the pre-defined CLI scripts (for example, defining a script named "init" would cause ambiguity when running `npm init`). They have added shortcuts for certain common user-defined scripts, but cannot do so categorically for all scripts.

Answer (score 6):

If using Yarn package manager, you can use a colon in the name to call the script from any workspace.

According to the yarn docs on [How to share scripts between workspaces?](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/qa#how-to-share-scripts-between-workspaces):

> Little-known Yarn feature: any script with a colon in its name (`build:foo`) can be called from any workspace.

Also, according to yarn docs on [CLI > run](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/run#details):

> Otherwise, if the specified name contains a colon character and if one of the workspaces in the project contains exactly one script with a matching name, then this script will get executed.

Comment: How to disable share script?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we name similar tasks that are grouped by naming them with a common prefix like this :

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:e2e": "node_modules/.bin/cypress open"
  },
```

Both `test` scripts purpose is testing the project code .

When we need to run `e2e` tests we use the script `npm run test:e2e` and when we need to run `integration` or `unit` tests we run the script `npm run test` .

Comment: You're kind of misusing "the same". When we say "X is the same as Y", then it is *absolute*. You can't later say "but X is a bit different than Y". It is or it isn't.

As to a better answer, you could say that "similar tasks are grouped by naming them with a common prefix". The colon is just a convention that people stuck with (perhaps due to historical reasons).